# Unit Test in NestJs using Jest

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

**So, I want to test a Controller, but I always get the same error, and I not really familiarized with Jest.**
I work with php and I already did some unit tests in phpUnit, but with Jest I'm really having some trouble to understand how to do.

Here is my error message

```
 ● Test suite failed to run

    SyntaxError: /home/webjump-nb103/Projects/development/workspace/stare/customer/src/customer/customer.controller.spec.ts: Unexpected token, expected ";" (13:26)

      11 | 
      12 | describe('Customer Controller', () => {
    > 13 |     let customerController: CustomerController;
         |                           ^
      14 |     let customerService: CustomerService;
      15 | 
      16 |     beforeAll(async () => {

      at Parser.raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/location.js:41:63)
      at Parser.unexpected (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/util.js:150:16)
      at Parser.semicolon (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/util.js:123:40)
      at Parser.parseVarStatement (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:703:10)
      at Parser.parseStatementContent (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:216:21)
      at Parser.parseStatement (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:146:17)
      at Parser.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:865:25)
      at Parser.parseBlockBody (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:841:10)
      at Parser.parseBlock (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:818:10)
      at Parser.parseFunctionBody (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:1964:24)
```

**My controller**

```
import {Controller, HttpStatus, Post, Res, Body, ValidationPipe, Put, Param, Get} from '@nestjs/common';

import {CreateCustomerDto} from './dto/customer/customer.dto';
import {CustomerService} from './customer.service';

@Controller('customer')
export class CustomerController {
    constructor(private readonly customerService: CustomerService) { }

    @Post()
    async createPost(@Res() res, @Body(ValidationPipe) createCustomerDto: CreateCustomerDto ) {
        const customer = await this.customerService.createCustomer(createCustomerDto);
        return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({
            customer: customer
        });
    }

    @Put('update/:id')
    async createUpdate(@Param('id') id: string, @Res() res, @Body(ValidationPipe) createCustomerDto: CreateCustomerDto) {

        const customer = await this.customerService.updateCustomer(createCustomerDto, id);

        return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({
            customer: customer
        });
    }
}
```

**My Service **

```
   import {Injectable} from '@nestjs/common';
import {Model} from 'mongoose';
import {InjectModel} from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import {Customer} from './interfaces/customer.interface';
import {CreateCustomerDto} from './dto/customer/customer.dto';

@Injectable()
export class CustomerService {
    constructor(@InjectModel('customer') private readonly customerModel: Model<Customer>) {}

    async createCustomer(createCustomerDto: CreateCustomerDto ): Promise<Customer> {
        const customer = new this.customerModel(createCustomerDto);
        return customer.save();
    }
async updateCustomer(createCustomerDto: CreateCustomerDto, id: string): Promise<Customer> {
    const customer = await this.customerModel
        .findByIdAndUpdate(id, createCustomerDto, {new: true});

    return customer;

}
```

}

**And my test**

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { CustomerController } from './customer.controller';
import {CustomerService} from './customer.service';
import {CreateCustomerDto} from './dto/customer/customer.dto';
import {Customer} from './interfaces/customer.interface';
import {InjectModel} from '@nestjs/mongoose';

jest.mock('./customer.service.ts');
jest.mock('./customer.controller.ts');
jest.mock('./interfaces/customer.interface.ts');

describe('Customer Controller', () => {
    let customerController: CustomerController;
    let customerService: CustomerService;

    beforeAll(async () => {
        const  module = await Test.createTestingModule({
        controllers: [CustomerController],
        providers: [CustomerService],
    }).compile();

        customerController = module.get(CustomerController);
        customerService = module.get<CustomerService>(CustomerService);
    });

    describe('Create Post', () => {
        const dto = new CreateCustomerDto();
        const res = 200;
        const customerModel: Customer;
        it('should return an collection of customer when created ', async () => {
            const expectedResult = new CustomerService(@InjectModel(customerModel<Customer>));
            jest.spyOn(customerService, 'createCustomer').mockResolvedValue(customerModel);
            expect(await customerController.createPost(res, dto)).toBe(expectedResult);
        });
    });
});

**Any thoughts ?**
```

Comment: What's your `jest.config.js` (or the part of the `package.json` that contains the jest config) look like? It looks like jest isn't recognizing the typescript code which makes me think `ts-jest` isn't being used

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, make sure you have your jest properly configured. Try to add/modify the following to your `package.json`

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
```